# iOS5 Change blue cell selection to custom image gradient without subclassing

Tags: ios, ios5, uikit

So in a `UITableViewCell` subclass this works great:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-highlight.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    self.selectedBackgroundView = imageView;
}
```

However I have a tableView that just uses standard table cells that aren't subclassed. I've tried all sorts of combinations of this as found in other answers with no luck:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-highlight.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn. Thought of one thing 30 seconds after posting this. Leaving it up in case it helps someone else.  My imageView didn't have a frame on it. Working code:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-highlight.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]];
    imageView.frame = cell.frame;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = imageView;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to mark your answer as an answer so it shows up in search as answered.